# I can't use django with python 3.7

Tags: python, django, pipenv

My original python version is 3.6.9 >> I have installed 3.7 manually >> then I tried to use pipenv to create a virtual environment >>

```
pipenv --python 3.7
```

every thing was fine until I tried to install django, I had this error and I don't know how to deal with it.

```
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches django
```

If I created my virtual environment using python 3.6, every thing works just right.

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4aj.png)

Comment: For future reference, please don't post images of code or output. Paste them in your question with code formatting (indented by four spaces) so people can read them easily and, if necessary, copy and paste them to test or search.

Comment: I tried but If i copied the error, it would be a mess

Comment: Why not you use `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment and then install Django in it.

Comment: If you are using ubuntu here is the way to install virtualenv https://gist.github.com/Geoyi/d9fab4f609e9f75941946be45000632b

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The problem is seen when dependent packages are kept to '*' in Pipfile. If we pin to right dependent package version for django. The error goes away.

I think the output of pipenv is not clear. May be it could print the mismatch in dependent package version.

Comment: I think the problem is that pipenv keeps searching inside my 3.6 python folder. How to make it searches inside 3.7